# Blur shadow on mdframed with rounded corners

Tags: mdframed, shadows

I got this definition for my mdframe style:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1%,debug]
  ]{beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster
  \usepackage{textpos}
%For Tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,%
    fadings,%
    shadings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\def\zangle{-20}
\def\xangle{20}
\usepackage[font={Large},labelfont={Large,color=MyBlue}]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%**************************************************************
\usepackage{setspace}
\definecolor{MyGreen-gray}{gray}{0.5383}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{RGB}{29,47,160}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=MyBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=MyBlue,fg=white}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{Blocco}{%
rightline=false,leftline=false,topline=false,bottomline=false, innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10,innertopmargin=10, innerbottommargin=10,linewidth=3.0pt, linecolor=black, roundcorner=4pt,frametitlefont=\Huge\textcolor{white} ,frametitlebelowskip=0.3cm,frametitleaboveskip=0.3cm, frametitlebackgroundcolor=MyBlue, backgroundcolor=MyBlue!7, shadow=true, shadowsize=5pt,middleextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue] 
    (P) --
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]P) -- 
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]P|-O) --
    (P|-O) -- cycle;
  }
},
secondextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P|-O)
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]P) -- 
    (P)} -- 
    (P|-O) -- ([xshift=\sshift]O);
  }
},
firstextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([yshift=-\sshift]P) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P) 
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]P|-O) -- 
    (P|-O)} -- ([yshift=-\sshift]P);
  }
},
singleextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P|-O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P) -- +(-6pt,0) --
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O) -- ([xshift=\sshift]O);
  }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 


%****************************************************************
%Titolo
\begin{textblock}{10.1}(2.6,-4)
{{\fontsize{120}{60}\selectfont S}}{{\fontsize{95}{60}\selectfont{\MakeUppercase{p }}}} {{\fontsize{120}{60}\selectfont A}}{{\fontsize{95}{60}\selectfont{\MakeUppercase{ct }}}}\\[1cm]
\begin{center}
{\huge{Quantum correlations}}
\end{center}
\end{textblock}     
    %****************************************************************

\begin{textblock}{10}(2.6,-2.5) 
\begin{mdframed}[style=Blocco,frametitle={Abstract}]
{\fontsize{44pt}{50pt}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]}
\end{mdframed}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{10}(2.6,4.5)  
\begin{block}{Abc}
\lipsum[1]
\end{block}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the pdf result has a problem with the rounded corners, as shown in the picture. My idea is that the rounded corners of the shadow of the mdframed box should be like to the classic block.

[image]

If anybody could solve this it would be very nice!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code to a complete document that is compilable, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you make your code a bit more minimal? We want a complete document, but only enough to show the problem. We don't need irrelevant content or packages. Just enough to reproduce the issue. Also, you are loading some things twice, which is not good practice generally.